# Using spring4d - TObjectDataset at runtime

Tags: delphi, spring4d

I am not able to properly create and populate spring4d ObjectDataSet at run time,an exception saying "Field ID has no dataset, (Creating fields at design-time work fine) here is my code:

```
 procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  _id: TIntegerField;
  _designation: TStringField;
  _dataset: TObjectDataSet;
  _artList: IList<TArticle>;
begin
  _artList := TCollections.CreateList<TArticle>(true);
  _artList.add(TArticle.Create(1, 'Article 1'));
  _artList.add(TArticle.Create(2, 'Article 2'));
  _artList.add(TArticle.Create(3, 'Article 3'));

  _dataset := TObjectDataSet.Create(self);
  _dataset.DataList := _artList as IObjectList;

  _id := TIntegerField.Create(self);
  _id.FieldKind := fkData;
  _id.Name := 'fid';
  _id.FieldName := 'ID';

  _designation := TStringField.Create(self);
  _designation.Size := 100;
  _designation.FieldKind := fkData;
  _designation.FieldName := 'Designation';

  with _dataset.Fields do
  begin
    add(_id);
    add(_designation);
  end;

  DataSource1.DataSet := _dataset;

  // self.DBEdit1.DataField := 'ID';
  // self.DBEdit2.DataField := 'Designation';

  _dataset.Open;
  _active := true;
end;
```

Comment: Finally, it work by removing the add block, and affect the _dataset to Field.Dataset(_id.Dataset:=_dataset;) property directly, what is the diff ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TFields.Add` does not set the DataSet property of the passed field. That is nothing specific to the Spring4D `TObjectDataSet` but inside of `Data.DB.pas`. When you are creating a field at designtime the designer sets the `DataSet` property of the field (see `DSDefine.pas`)

Comment: thank you, i have tested other drived Dataset(TADODataset, Tmemdata), and i found the same error result, for this raison, i try others way, and  thank you for your great works.